# Theme specific login redirection?

Tags: 7, redirection, theming

Anyone know of a way within the theme to redirect to a different url after login?

**Theme #1:**
Eg. User goes to `www.examplesite.com` logs in and is taken to `www.examplesite.com/front`

**Theme #2:**
Eg. User goes to `www.examplesite.com` logs in and is taken to `subdomain.examplesite.com`

I know of modules that allow us to do this for the entire site but have not found a way to do it just for a single theme.

Background: its for the mobile site UX.

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/login_destination would seem to offer a possibility to use custom PHP snippets as conditions for destinations.

So you need to find out which theme is being used. As I cannot fathom how you are changing your theme in the first place, I cannot help you with that.

Comment: I tried this but can't seem to find where to add the PHP snippets. Another option is using rules if there was a way to add a theme condition.